# MS Access 2010 tab control bug

Tags: ms-access, tabs, ms-access-2010, controls

Developing new application in Access 2010, that includes use of MS supplied tab control.

Evidence is there is a bug with the control so the only way to allow multiple rows is to set Use Theme attribute to No. However the downside of this is that it does not allow the setting of any colours. Result it technically works but looks terrible.

This workaround is documented by microsoft at
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_other/microsoft-access-2010-how-to-create-multiple-row/d0a6f738-1a3a-4e70-920c-c24d55bb8a0f [^]

I really wish to avoid have to use a third party control.

Can anyone confirm this behaviour, and advise if there are any other workarounds to allow the setting of some colours?

Comment: You could try using NavigationForm which allows multiple rows of buttons.  (you will have to rewrite your "path" to controls)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this bug presents in MS Access 2010.
As a workaround you can use navigation control, but it recreates page every time when you open it and has some more problems, personally I don't like it and trying to avoid using this control.

As additional workaround you can use the same tab control, but select style with no tabs. Implement tabs using command buttons or even pictures. It will require some additional coding, but it will give you much more opportunities for design